# Cannot load projects AT ALL in visual studio community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, installation, loading

I've been having this problem ever since my computer somehow abruptly decided to restart while I was working on a project.

Whenever I try to load a project now - any project - a warning message comes up saying that "The visual c++ project system package did not load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension." Clicking either "yes" or "no" to "Continue to show this error message?" leads to a completely blank IDE, and trying to open or create any project or file after that leads to an error saying "Expected 1 exports with contract name "Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ISolutionAttachedCollectionService" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints."

In ActivityLog.xml, the description of the warning shows up as:

User:IdeUser, TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.: VssUnauthorizedException during ImplicitSignIn
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsyncImpl>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__76`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.IdeConnector.<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext() (ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

I've seen this issue floating around a lot on stackoverflow and other websites, and the suggested solution has always been to delete %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache and then restart visual studio. However, this has not worked for me thus far. Nothing - all the way to deleting said folder and then repairing or outright reinstalling visual studio - has worked. I'm at wit's end. I just don't know what else I can do, short of wiping my hard drive and reformatting Windows. Could anyone here offer any help or advice?

Comment: Have you sign in VS 2015 with your Microsoft account? In the top right corner of VS, you will find a colored box with your name and click the down arrow and Account Settings, then Sign out and restart the VS, sign in with your Microsoft account again. Or open cmd as administrator and navigate to the Vs 2015 installation folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE, run the command: devenv /safemode to check if the installed extensions blocked it. If it works fine, go to Extension and Updates and remove the installed extensions one by one to find it.

Comment: Hi Sara, unfortunately that has not worked...even after several reinstalls and trying the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Hi Fergus, it seems the suddenly restart corrupted the VS or your system files, please click Start and scroll down to the Visual Studio 2017 folder, expand it, run the ‘Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017’ as administrator and run the command: devenv /resetuserdata or devenv /setup to test. Go to Windows update, check if all pending updates are installed or could you roll back the previous OS backup before this issue popup?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Fortunately, by now, I've resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi Fergus, I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for your sharing, please mark it as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The steps I took were thus:

1. Uninstalled VS
2. Uninstalled visual c++ redistributable from 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013... (x64 and x86)
3. Went through my computer and permanently deleted everything with the words "visual" and/or "studio"
4. Uninstalled Xamarin
5. Reinstalled visual studio
6. Run cmd as admin
7. Navigate to directory of visual studio
8. Type "devenv /Setup" (case-sensitive)
9. ???
10. Login again (with another outlook account)
11. Profit